# フッターメニューの「フィードバック」が途中で改行されてしまっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

サイトのフッターメニューの「フィードバック」が単語の途中で改行されてしまっている

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ブラウザーバージョンとOSを教えてくれますか？そして、モニターは何画素ですか？（例えば、1024x768等）

Comment: 環境は以下です。  Safari Version 7.1 (9537.85.10.17.1)  OS X 10.9.5  Display Resolution 2880x1800

Comment: 直しましたか？同じ環境で再現が出来ないですが、tomuteさん側でまだ怒っていますか？

Comment: 修正されていることを確認しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

修正されました。対応ありがとうございます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]